# async calls to google service using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-geocoder

I have one array

```
SchoolAddress[0] = Abelsvej 98, 4100, Ringsted;
SchoolAddress[1] = Prstevej 19, 4100, Ringsted;
SchoolAddress[2] = Haraldsvej 77, 4100, Ringsted;
```

I have to get latitude & longitude for this address.

I am using google geocoder for this.

```
for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) 
{
    var address = schools[i][1];
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) 
    {
        var location = results[0].geometry.location;
        schoolslat[i] = location.lat() + ', ' + location.lng();
    });
}
```

Here what happens is as call takes some time, the values coming from call do not go to proper schoolslat[i].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [**closure**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work) to *freeze* variable `i` in your request:

```
for (var i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) 
{
    (function(i){
        var address = schools[i];
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) 
        {
            var location = results[0].geometry.location;
            schoolslat[i] = location.lat() + ', ' + location.lng();
        });
    }(i));
}
```

**UPD**:

[**JSFiddle** example](http://jsfiddle.net/fedosov/Ypf8v/7/).

Comment: Can you provide array content of `schools`?

Comment: my array is [Abelsvej 98, 4100, Ringsted],
[Almstoftevej 71, 4100, Ringsted],
[Balstrupvej 35, 4100, Ringsted],
[Ejlstrupvej 101, 4100, Ringsted],
[Ejlstrupvej 101 C 101, 4100, Ringsted],
[Ejlstrupvej 90 90, 4100, Ringsted],
[Haraldsvej 7 7, 4100, Ringsted],
[Løngangen 43 65, 4100, Ringsted],
[Vetterslev Bygade 21 21, 4100, Ringsted],
[Østergade 25, Høm 25, 4100, Ringsted],
[Østergade 3, høm 3, 4100, Ringsted]

Comment: In that case `schools[i][1]` always gives you the second character of an address as a search term, so you searching for `b`, `l`, `a`, `j` etc.

Comment: I fixed this example http://jsfiddle.net/fedosov/Ypf8v/10/ (missing semicolon). But you must provide some timeout between requests, otherwise you get `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28152/discussion-between-fedosov-and-vaibhav-shah)

Comment: Can we do something so that script will go to further process only after receiving these values

Comment: @vaibhavshah yes, you can use callback for example.

Comment: After each request you can check whether all adresses already found and fire the callback if true.